# Text clipping issue with size calculated from MeasureString

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have a sample string for which i calculates the size and draws the string in the form through below code,

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   Rectangle textRectangle;
   string text = "testing the size 1 testing the size 1 testing the size 1 testing the size 1";

   public Form1()
   {
       InitializeComponent();

       Size textSize = this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(text, this.Font, 100).ToSize();

       textRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, textSize.Width, textSize.Height);
   }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       base.OnPaint(e);
       using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue))
       {
           e.Graphics.DrawString(text, this.Font, brush, textRectangle);
       }
   }
}
```

My issue is the textRectangle calculated from the simple string is not sufficient to draw in form. Please refer to attached image, that some of the given string is not drawn.

[image]

**Could anyone please update me, why the size calculated from MeasureString() is not enough to draw using the DrawString() method?**

Comment: Works fine for me. Not that you should be using `CreateGraphics()`, and if you decide to anyway, you should be disposing the `Graphics` instance you created. But I can't reproduce your complaint. What is the `Font` set to? What OS version are you using? What is the screen display resolution and font scaling?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - see the resolved answer.

Answer (score 0):

The above mentioned issue is resolved when using **MeasureTrailingSpaces formatflags** . Use the below code,

```
StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces);
Size textSize = this.CreateGraphics().MeasureString(text, this.Font, 100, stringFormat).ToSize();
textRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, textSize.Width, textSize.Height);
```

While calculating size, the spaces are not considered, so to consider spaces in string, MeasureTrailingSpaces have to be used.

Comment: How does this address the problem? You haven't even shown any code that _demonstrates_ the problem, but trailing spaces at the end of each line should not affect the bounding rect as a whole. There's no reason to believe that this answer actually solves whatever problem you have.

Comment: Can't you see the code for calculating the textRectangle using MeasureString and uses the DrawString for drawing the string with the calculated textRectangle

Comment: You posted code. But not code that reproduces the problem you describe. Can't you see the comment I posted hours ago explaining that? Your question is insufficiently documented, so any answer is necessarily also insufficient.